# MYSQL copy and increase existing rows

Tags: mysql

Hi I have an table allNews that has 150 rows set up as follows newsID = autoInc:

```
newsID    newsIDInt    siteID    catID    title
31        1            3         4        Item 1 
32        2            3         4        Item 2

uoto
180       150          3         4        Item 150
```

I need to duplicate into the same table so the result would be

```
newsID    newsIDInt    siteID    catID    title
181       1            3         5        Item 1 
182       2            3         5        Item 2

uoto
230       150          3         5        Item 150
```

ie duplicate and change field catID to 5.

Is this possible using a mysql script?

MrWarby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid to specify the newsID (if it is autoincrement) and force the catID to 5:

```
    insert into allNews (newsIDInt, siteID, catID, title)
    select newsIDInt, siteID, 5, title from allNews
```

Answer (score 2):

You can insert into the table and select the values you need (adjusting as neccessary):

```
INSERT INTO allNews 
        SELECT newsId + 150, newsIDInt, siteID,catID+1,title 
        FROM allNews
        WHERE newsId BETWEEN 31 AND 180;
```

(Though you may want to have an auto increment take care of the newsId field).

Comment: OP says `newsID = autoInc`. So no explicit input for `newsId` is required. And a `limit 150` is required to restrict further selection, if some exists.

Comment: @Ravinder Good point, I'll limit the select to only the rows the op mentioned.